# I have proplem type with Reactjs and Typescript .I set type dataResponse .I feel overlap ! How to short code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I feel it overlap id,name,description,total ! I feel code not good.

```
export interface LanguagePhase{
    id:number,
    name:number,
    description:string,
    idLang:number
}
export interface Phase{
    id:number,
    active:number,
    name:number,
    description:string,
    total:number,
    phaseId:number,
    phasesTranslate:LanguagePhase[]
}
export interface DataResponse{
    id:number,
    active:number,
    name:number,
    total:number,
    description:string,
    expertName:string,
    courseId:number,
    listPhases:Phase[]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm building upon @Kush R.'s answer with some example code. There are many ways to write this.

Extracting the properties which are in all three (`id`, `name`, `description`) is pretty straight-forward starting point, I'll call it `Response` since @Kush R. did.

The properties which are in two of the three (`active`, `total`) can be handled multiple ways.

- You can create an interface `ActiveProperties` which contains just the added properties.  An interface can extend multiple interfaces, so `Phase` and `DataResponse` would extend both `ActiveProperties` and `Response`.  Like this: `export interface Phase extends ActiveProperties, Response {`
- You can create an interface `ActiveResponse` which extends `Response` and adds these properties.  Since `ActiveResponse` contains all of the properties of `Response` you can extend it in `Phase` and `DataResponse` without having to also include `Response`.  Like so `interface Phase extends ActiveResponse {`.

Deciding which to use is partly just a personal preference, and partly depends on the other types in your codebase.  Are there other types/interfaces aside from these which have properties `active` and `total`?  Do those types also have the properties of `Response` or not?  Think about things like that.

Here's one possibility for the complete set.  Note that this resulting code is not much shorter than what you have written, and is potentially a lot more confusing.

```
export interface Response {
    id: number;
    name: number;
    description: string;
}

export interface LanguagePhase extends Response {
    idLang: number;
}

export interface ActiveResponse extends Response {
    active: number;
    total: number;
}

export interface Phase extends ActiveResponse {
    phaseId: number;
    phasesTranslate: LanguagePhase[];
}

export interface DataResponse extends ActiveResponse {
    expertName: string;
    courseId: number;
    listPhases: Phase[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple interfaces and then extend an interface if needed. The properties in an interface should be logical.

This [Example](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/interface-extending-interfaces.html) shows how to extend interfaces

Update:

By logical, I meant the grouping of properties in an interface should be required at the same time, its more efficient that way. For example, if 3 properties lets say id, name and description are always needed together, they should be the only properties in a single interface (lets call it Response). In case another property is needed, a new interface could be created with the new property and the new interface could extend the Response interface

Comment: I understand . Thanks you.

Comment: This is the right idea but I'm not sure what you mean by "the properties in an interface should be logical".

Comment: By logical, I meant the grouping of properties in an interface should be required at the same time, its more efficient that way. For example, if 3 properties lets say id, name and description are always needed together, they should be the only properties in a single interface (lets call it Response). In case another property is needed, a new interface could be created with the new property and the new interface could extend the Response interface.

Comment: I completely agree with you. Consider adding that clarification the answer itself, perhaps with an example. It's good advice but "logical" doesn't entail that.

Comment: @AluanHaddad That is a good suggestion. I will do that. Also @ Linda Paiste has done a pretty good job of explaining it.